# How can I update a website by publishing to a new address, and then forwarding to it?

Tags: asp.net, html, web-applications, web

If I want to update my web site without there being a break in its functioning (almost) I thought I might publish the new version to a new folder, and after it has been uploaded - simply "point" to it from the normal url of the site.

Can this be done? I don't mean only to have `MySite.com` point to `MySite.com/folder1/default.aspx`, I mean that *every* page on the site will be that way (e.g. `MySite.com/A.aspx` will point to `MySite.com/folder1/A.aspx`). If so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a 301 redirect to point from the old URLs to the new URLs.

I found these instructions for doing this on IIS. Hopefully they are useful.

> IS Redirect
>
> - In internet services manager, right click on the file or folder you wish to redirect
> - Select the radio titled "a redirection to a URL".
> - Enter the redirection page
> - Check "The exact url entered above" and the "A permanent redirection for this resource"
> - Click on 'Apply'

Comment: Seems to be working on a little trial site I created. Thanks.